# Need to get data combining 3 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have three tables

Table: `eformdynamic` ef:

```
+---------------------------+---------+
| userid (refers en-userid) | field12 |
+---------------------------+---------+
|                        12 |   99999 |
|                        13 |  888888 |
|                        14 |   77777 |
|                        15 |   66666 |
+---------------------------+---------+
```

`Enterprise` en:

```
+----------+--------+
| loginid  | userid |
+----------+--------+
| 20065678 |     12 |
| 20065679 |     13 |
| 20065680 |     14 |
| 20065681 |     15 |
+----------+--------+
```

`List`: l

```
+------+----------------------------+
| name | itemid (refers ef-field12) |
+------+----------------------------+
| ABC  |                      99999 |
| DEF  |                     888888 |
| GHI  |                      77777 |
| JKL  |                      66666 |
+------+----------------------------+
```

Output required:

```
+------------+--------+
| en-loginid | l-name |
+------------+--------+
|   20065678 | ABC    |
|   20065679 | DEF    |
|   20065680 | GHI    |
|   20065681 | JKL    |
+------------+--------+
```

Please help me join the tables to get desired output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty straight-forward `join` here -- try something . . . -- http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
select enterprise.loginid,list.name 
from  enterprise
inner join eformdynamic on enterprise.userid = eformdynamic.userid
inner join list on eformdynamic.field12 = list.itemid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join, like this:

```
SELECT
   en.loginid AS end_loginid, C.name AS l-name
FROM eformdynamic ef
   INNER JOIN enterprise en
      ON ef.userid = en.userid
   INNER JOIN list l
      ON ef.field12 = l.itemid
```